# Как правильно расставлять знаки препинания в предложении? Есть ли общая схема?

Tags: пунктуация

Почему в русском языке столько толкований одного предложения? Авторские знаки; здесь нужно так; а здесь по-другому. Я столько бьюсь с пунктуацией и никак не могу научиться правильной расстановке знаков препинания.Посоветуйте, где можно этому научиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что освоение пунктуационной грамотности **надо начинать с изучения грамматики: вы должны научиться четко определять базовые грамматические конструкции по всем темам.**

А потом уже применяйте правила. К примеру, автор текста решает вопрос  об обособлении оборота. Если он хочет выделить его, то СТРОИТ предложение так, что по правилам оно должно выделяться. Если вы работаете с авторским текстом, то предложение уже построено, и вы должны применить правило к его существующей структуре.

Но иногда одно и то же предложение допускает обособление и необособление (например, оборот перед определяемым существительным). Это и есть авторское решение: грамматика одна, а пунктуация разная. И выбор в этом случае делается по смыслу. Если мы хотим придать обороту дополнительное обстоятельственное значение, то обособляем его; если хотим ограничиться определительным значением, то не обособляем.

ПРИМЕР. Обособление согласованных определений (основные идеи)

Общий принцип решения. При обособлении определений проводится анализ их СИНТАКСИЧЕСКОЙ РОЛИ, а также ПОЗИЦИИ относительно определяемого слова, при этом соблюдаются следующие правила:

1. Определение в составе сказуемого.
    Не обособляется определение, входящее В СОСТАВ СКАЗУЕМОГО.
2. Определение не сочетается с определяемым словом.
   Если определение НЕ СОЧЕТАЕТСЯ с определяемым словом, то есть не образует словосочетания (например, с личным местоимением), то оно ВСЕГДА ОБОСОБЛЯЕТСЯ.
3. Определение в нормальной позиции.
   Определение, стоящее перед определяемым словом, находится В НОРМАЛЬНОЙ ПОЗИЦИИ и, как правило, не обособляется. Обособление определений в нормальной позиции производится в виде исключения с целью его смыслового выделения (актуализации);
4. Определение в инверсированной позиции.
   Определение, стоящее после определяемого слова или на расстоянии от него, находится  в ИНВЕРСИРОВАННОЙ (изменённой) позиции и, как правило, обособляется. Такое  определение не обособляется в виде исключения в том  случае, когда оно тесно связано по смыслу с определяемым словом и является смысловым центом высказывания.

Comment: А ссылочку в Интернете не можете посоветовать по этой теме, где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Я вам рассказала о методике, которую можно применить к любому учебнику по пунктуации (например, правила Лопатина http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php). Лучше не запоминать изложенные правила, а провести их анализ: составить для себя перечень основных синтаксических конструкций, определить основные идеи решения.  В дополнении к ответу я приведу такой план по теме «Обособление согласованных определений».

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.Только ссылка ведет в никуда.

Comment: >Только ссылка ведет в никуда.  
  
Сюда она ведет.)))
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php  
Только я вам не советую учить что-то по справочникам, а не учебникам.

Comment: Уже нашел.

Answer (score 0):

> Почему в русском языке столько толкований одного предложения?

О чем вы? Грамматическая омонимия вещь в русском довольно редкая. Примеры не приведете?

> Авторские знаки;

Здесь действительно есть расхождения в понимании. Я считаю, что авторские знаки это знаки, ***не противоречащие*** общим правилам, но проставляемые автором при желании подчеркнуть необычность вкладываемого им смысла. Т.е. идущие не от безграмотности автора, а от его заботы о понимании читающим.

> здесь нужно так; а здесь по-другому.

Это о чем?

> Я столько бьюсь с пунктуацией и никак не могу научиться правильной расстановке знаков препинания.Посоветуйте, где можно этому научиться.

В школе.

А в чем именно сложность-то? Вы не запоминаете правила? Или не знаете, как их применить?  Или, может, постоянно хочется нарушить правило потому, что вам так "лучше видно"?

Что могу сказать наверняка, так это то, что единой схемы "научиться" нет и быть не может. Знаете, есть люди, которые не в состоянии усвоить ни одно "умно" сформулированное правило (ну вот как у Веры)просто потому, что у них не то полушарие ведущее. Им надо через практику идти. А есть аналитические умы, которые не будут себя чувствовать спокойно, пока в правиле не будет понятна каждая буква. Их сколько не заставляй зубрить правила, исключения и примеры, толку не будет. Я вот тоже себя к последним отношу. Тут сложности другого порядка. Все правила давно известны и на подкорке записаны, а применять их на практике не умеют или не хотят.

Попробуйте для начала взять понятный вам текст - и подумать, зачем стоит каждый знак. По результату сами поймет, по какому пути двигаться. В любом случае не стоит гнаться за быстрым результатом и углубляться в частности по каждому правилу, если вы не понимаете его в целом (это как у Vera - столько понаписано, а суть понятно только если есть некоторый базовый уровень).

Comment: Да. Написано у нее не очень понятно. У меня трудности с запоминанием правил. Полушария, видимо, смещены с орбиты. :) Практика -- это дело хорошее. Буду тренироваться. За внимание благодарю.